# Pre-Pending Date To Each Entry In First Column of a CSV File Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns, Time and Data.

`Time,Data
16:44:23,Connection Succesful
18:22:44,Connection Unsuccessful
19:33:23,Connection Waiting
...and so on`

The time column doesn't have the date pre-pended to it. I am trying to work on a script that adds the date '**2/5/2018** ' before the time for each entry in the Time column.

the new output should be:

`Time,Data
2/5/2018 16:44:23,Connection Succesful
2/5/2018 18:22:44,Connection Unsuccessful
2/5/2018 19:33:23,Connection Waiting`

Please help as my code is not working.

`import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('/home/myuser/timedata.csv'))
for row in reader:
    '2/5/2018 '+row['Time']
    print row['Time']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use pandas!

```
pip install pandas 

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv.csv')
```

And apply this customs function to your time column

```
df = df.assign(Time=df.Time.apply(lambda x : '2/5/2018 '+x))
```

you can convert back your dataframe using to_csv method

```
df.to_csv()
```